# foreach loop variable accessing from outside

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

How to access variable that is in the foreach loop from outside it ? when I try to do it, it only takes the last value. I have to click on a button which open a wind and I need to use the value of the row where I clicked, but it only takes the last value.

I use this into the loop 
`<c:set var="q" value="${p.getIdUser()}"  />`

and outside the loop I do this 
`<a href='DeleteUser?id=${q}'>`

but it takes only the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can put row row no with c:set var to identify uniquely each c set variable

```
        q+Row_number As q${forEach_varStatus_variable.count}
```

Like

```
 <c:set var="q${forEach_varStatus_variable.count}" value="${p.getIdUser()}"/>
```

OutSide ForEach:

```
 <a href='DeleteUser?id=${q1}'>
 <a href='DeleteUser?id=${q2}'>
```

Or access c set as q+Row_number.